# Keras predict repeated columns

Tags: r, keras, predict

I have a question related to keras model code in R. I have finished training the model and need to predict. Predicting a line is very fast, but my data has 2000,000,000 rows and nearly 200 columns, with a structure like the attached image.
[Datastructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7HWmW.png)
I don't know if anyone has any suggestions on which method to use so that predict can run quickly and use less memory. I created a matrix according to the table as shown in order to predict, each matrix is ​​200,000x200 dimensions. Then I use sapply to predict all the remaining matrices. However, even though predict is fast for each matrix, but creating the matrix is ​​slow, so it makes the model run twice or three times as long, and that is not taking into account the sapply step. I wonder if keras has a "smart" way to know that in each of his matrix, the last N columns that are exactly the same? I google and see someone talking about RepeatVector but I don't quite understand and it seems that this is only used for training? I already have the model and just need to predict.
Thank you so much everyone!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most performant ways to feed keras models locally is by creating a `tf.data.Dataset` object. Please take a look at the `tfdatasets` R package for guides and example usage.

Comment: This looks like a very nice package. I will go back to edit the question when I figure out how to use it for my problem.